# Inserting current user and date into table using trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a trigger that will log the current date, the user and what action was performed out of an insert, delete or an update on a specific table.

I am trying to store that data in a separate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BORROWER_CHANGES (
ChangeDate DATE NOT NULL,
UserName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Action VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL);
```

This is my trigger so far:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BORROWER_MODIFICATION
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON borrower
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO borrower_changes (ChangeDate, UserName, Action)
VALUES ('SysDate', 'User', 'INSERT');
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
INSERT INTO borrower_changes (ChangeDate, UserName, Action)
VALUES ('SysDate', 'User', 'UPDATE');
ELSIF DELETING THEN
INSERT INTO borrower_changes (ChangeDate, UserName, Action)
VALUES ('SysDate', 'User', 'DELETE');
END IF;
END;
```

When trying to insert data into the table that will cause the trigger to go off I get this error:

> Error report -
> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I have dropped the trigger and am having no issues with the data being inserted without the trigger so it definitely seems to be an issue with my trigger.

I looked it up and the most common cause seems to be the date format not matching up, I used this to try to find my date format:

```
select *
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

And it appears that it is 'DD/MON/RR' is that possibly an issue? I am new to SQL and the date format stuff always throws me off, I have researched a bit and can't seem to find a way to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BORROWER_MODIFICATION
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON borrower
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO borrower_changes (ChangeDate, UserName, Action)
    VALUES (sysdate, user, 'INSERT');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO borrower_changes (ChangeDate, UserName, Action)
    VALUES (sysdate, user, 'UPDATE');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO borrower_changes (ChangeDate, UserName, Action)
    VALUES (sysdate, user, 'DELETE');
  END IF;
END;
```

You want the [sysdate](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/sysdate.php) built-in function. You are using a string literal.
You want the [user](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/username.php) built-in function. You are using a string literal.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I overlooked that, thankyou so much